# While Synchroning sql server & android sqlite : I got OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, wcf, json, sqlite

I ahve do to synchronization between sql server & sqlite.While doing that I got OutOfMemoryError.Please tell me how we can avoid or from my code is there any unwanted or getting more memory statement is there? Please guide me.

Where can I use `System.gc()` ?

From the service result come string as JSON.

```
{"Table1" : 
[{"ActiveStatus" : "1","AddressLine1" : "223, Dambulla Road,","AddressLine2" : "Galewela.","AddressLine3" : "","AlphaSearchCode" : "New Lanka Hardware -","BusinessUnit" : "MASS","ContactName" : "","CreatedBy" : "Nazar ","CreatedOn" : "Oct 3 2005 6:16PM","CreditLimit" : "100.00","CurrencyCode" : " ","CurrencyProcessingRequired" : "0","CurrentBalance" : "0.00","EMailAddress" : "","FaxNumber" : "","LastInvoiceDate" : "","LastPaymentDate" : "","LastPaymentValue" : "0.00","NewRetailerFlag" : "","OSOrdersPendingBase" : "0.00","OSOrdersPendingCurr" : "0.00","OnStopFlag" : "0","OnStopReasonCode" : " ","PaymentMethodCode" : "CQ","PriceGroup" : "MKT ","PricingMethod" : "0","RetailerCategoryCode" : "01 ","RetailerClassCode" : "C ","RetailerCode" : "0001 ","RetailerCodeSon" : " ","RetailerName" : "New Lanka Hardware - Galewela","RetailerTypeCode" : "02 ","RetailerTypeFlag" : "0","SalesExecutiveCode" : "THPOS ","SalesType" : "","SettlementTermsCode" : "C90","ShortAddress" : "Galewela11","StatusFlag" : "0","TelephoneNumber" : "","TempCreditApprovedInvNo" : "","TemporaryCreditAllowed" : "","TemporaryCreditApprovedBy" : "","TemporaryCreditApprovedOn" : "","TemporaryCreditLimit" : "0.00","TemporaryCreditUpto" : "","TerritoryCode" : "0001","TotalCreditsNotAllocated" : "0.00","TownCode" : "GW ","TradeSchemeGroup" : "DS ","VATCode" : "V0","VATRegistrationNo" : ""}]}
```

This is one recored.Real time it will come 1000 or more records.After getting this JSON result ,it want to make update statement or insert statement.

I did like this way coding:

```
  public void loadDownloadData() {
    SoapPrimitive responsePrimitiveData;
    //Loop Table list
    for (int i = 0; i < SelectedTablesName.size(); i++) {
    try {
    responsePrimitiveData = soapPrimitiveData(SelectedTablesName.get(i));
             if (responsePrimitiveData != null) {

                try {
                    String result = responsePrimitiveData.toString();
                    if(!result.equals("0")){
                        JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(result);
                        JSONArray array = jsonobject.getJSONArray("Table1");
                        int max = array.length();

                        String actualtable = getAndroidTablename(SelectedTablesName.get(i));
                        String updateType = getTableUpdateType(SelectedTablesName.get(i));
                        boolean isRecordAvailable = isTableRecords(SelectedTablesName.get(i));
                        String[] strWhereField = getTablePrimaryKey(SelectedTablesName.get(i),strBusinessUnit);

                        if (updateType.equals("1")) {
                            // Loop each table data
                            for (int j = 0; j < max; j++) {
                                JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(j);
                                JSONArray names = obj.names();
                                StringBuffer strFields = new StringBuffer();
                                //StringBuffer strValues = new StringBuffer();
                                String[] strToFields = new String[names.length()];
                                String[] strToFieldsVal = new String[names.length()];
                                // getting the Json name, values in separate string array
                                for (int k = 0; k < names.length(); k++) {
                                    strToFields[k] = names.getString(k);
                                    if (obj.getString(names.getString(k)) == null) {
                                        strToFieldsVal[k] = "";
                                    } else {
                                        if (obj.getString(names.getString(k)).equals(" ")) {
                                            strToFieldsVal[k] = "";
                                        } else {
                                            strToFieldsVal[k] = obj.getString(names.getString(k)).replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                                        }
                                    }
                                    strFields.append(names.getString(k) + ",");
                                } // end of json for loop
                                strFields.deleteCharAt(strFields.length() - 1);
                                if (isRecordAvailable) {
                                    String[] strWhereFieldVal = new String[strWhereField.length];
                                    StringBuffer whereFields = new StringBuffer();
                                    // making update calues where part
                                    for (int a = 0; a < strWhereField.length; a++) {
                                        strWhereFieldVal[a] = obj.getString(strWhereField[a]);
                                        String whereValues = obj.getString(strWhereField[a]).replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                                        whereFields.append(strWhereField[a]+ "= '" + whereValues+ "' and ");
                                    }
                                    // removing "and" from the end
                                    whereFields.delete(whereFields.length() - 4,whereFields.length());
                                    updateTableRecords(actualtable,strToFields, strToFieldsVal, whereFields.toString(),strWhereFieldVal);
                                } else {
                                    insertTableRecords(actualtable,strToFields, strToFieldsVal);

                                }
                            }
                        } 

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Log.i("***" ,SelectedTablesName.get(i));
        System.out.println(" -- " + SelectedTablesName.get(i));
        try {
            updateSuccessfulTableSoap(SelectedTablesName.get(i));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

How we can do the garbage collection here.I want to make it string , string[] , stringBuilder reference to null or what can i do for this.

Error is :

```
     08-11 17:26:53.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(348): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
08-11 17:26:53.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(348): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
08-11 17:26:53.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(348):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
08-11 17:26:53.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(348):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
08-11 17:26:53.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(348):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
08-11 17:26:53.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(348):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
08-11 17:26:53.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(348):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
08-11 17:26:53.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(348):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
08-11 17:26:53.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(348):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
08-11 17:26:53.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(348):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
08-11 17:26:53.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(348): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
08-11 17:26:53.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(348):     at java.nio.CharBuffer.put(CharBuffer.java:532)
08-11 17:26:53.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(348):     at java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder.allocateMore(CharsetDecoder.java:263)
08-11 17:26:53.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(348):     at java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder.decode(CharsetDecoder.java:218)
08-11 17:26:53.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(348):     at java.nio.charset.Charset.decode(Charset.java:488)
08-11 17:26:53.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(348):     at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:181)
08-11 17:26:53.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(348):     at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:141)
08-11 17:26:53.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(348):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:96)
08-11 17:26:53.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(348):     at com.xont.controller.DownlaodTableActivity.soapPrimitiveData(DownlaodTableActivity.java:640)
08-11 17:26:53.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(348):     at com.xont.controller.DownlaodTableActivity.loadDownloadData(DownlaodTableActivity.java:247)
08-11 17:26:53.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(348):     at com.xont.controller.DownlaodTableActivity$BackgroundAsyncTask.doInBackground(DownlaodTableActivity.java:795)
08-11 17:26:53.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(348):     at com.xont.controller.DownlaodTableActivity$BackgroundAsyncTask.doInBackground(DownlaodTableActivity.java:1)
08-11 17:26:53.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(348):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
08-11 17:26:53.040: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(348):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
```

**Edited**

This is json processing

```
 public void getSoapResponseTableDataJson(SoapPrimitive node,
        ArrayList<String> strings ,String loadedtable) throws JSONException {
        String result = node.toString();
        JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray array = jsonobject.getJSONArray("Table1");
        int max = array.length();

         HashMap<String, String> applicationSettings = new HashMap<String,String>();
            for(int i = 0; i < max; i++){
                String value = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("value");
                String name = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
                applicationSettings.put(name, value);
            }



    }
```

Please help me how to get the solution for this....

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You are using up a lot of memory to form the JSON objects from the server response. This is because the standard JSON libraries that come with Android use the **entire** response to form a tree of JSON objects.

When you deal with large amounts of data (to avoid an `OutOfMemoryError`), you need to form the JSON objects one after the other as you read them from the input stream. Take a look at [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/), it allows you to parse the JSON from a stream, significantly reducing memory consumption.

When you receive a response from the server use `HttpResponse.getEntity` to get a hold of the `HttpEntity` on which you can call `HttpEntity.getContent` to get an `InputStream`.

Comment: This is good suggestion.But my case response coming String json that means `{"Table1" : [{"ActiveStatus" : "1","AddressLine1"}]}` like this. How we can use `HttpResponse.getEntity`  & `HttpEntity.getContent` Please guide me...

Comment: I'm not familiar with the SOAP library you are using. In this case you may be using `ServiceConnection.openInputStream`